# Can’t instal Big Sur or enter Internet Recovery after wiping HD (error 1008f)

Tags: disk-utility, startup, recovery

I’m giving my 2018 MacBook Pro (which had Big Sur) to my sister so I wiped it by booting into internet recovery, and using disk utility to erase Macintosh HD and Macintosh HD Data.

After I did that I could no longer boot into internet recovery or install Big Sur. It would try with a spinning globe icon and then fail with an error of something like -1008f.

Good news. If you run into this problem apple solved it for me: you need to log into iCloud on another Mac/iPhone and turn off Find My Mac on the Mac you are trying to reinstall on.

So that is an answer I couldn’t find anywhere and hope helps someone else. The question is: how should I have done this wipe?

I followed apples steps. Is it:

1. Log out of find my Mac
2. Boot into internet recovery and only delete Macintosh HD - data
3. Do something else?

At the apple store they went a step above in disk utility, did show devices, and deleted the parent or Macintosh HD and the data partition then reinstalled.